# is there an OR expression in regex for clojure?

Tags: regex, clojure

I have a string with two possible out comes it will either be divided by `&|` or just `|` is there a way of doing an or expression to determine which of these is true in regex?

Comment: Make `&` optional `&?\|` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you mean that you wish to match strings with either `&|` or `|` and then, in the case of a match, check which case it was that matched?

If so, you can do by matching with a regex in which `&` is optional -- as suggested by HamZa in a comment on the question -- and using `re-find` or capture groups to capture the matching part of the string which you can then examine:

```
(re-find #"&?\|" "asdf|adsf")
;= "|"

(re-find #"&?\|" "asdf&|asdf")
;= "&|"
```

With capture groups (use `peek` to get at a vector's final element):

```
(re-matches #".*[^&](&?\|).*" "asdf&|asdf")
;= ["asdf&|asdf" "&|"]
```